# Csv Helper is writing all records Even after class Mappings

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using Csv Helper by joshclose to write csv file. I have used class mapping. According to documents I don't need to explicitly ignore non used properties in class mapping since csv helper will only use properties that are mentioned in mappings but this is not happening. Here is the code.

```
public sealed class ExportInvoicesCsvMap : CsvClassMap<Invoice>
    {
        public ExportInvoicesCsvMap()
        {
            Map(i => i.Number).Index(0).Name("Number");
            Map(i => i.SupplierName).Index(1).Name("Supplier Name");

        }
    }
```

This is where I register class mapping.

```
List<Invoice> result = _invoiceService.GetInvoices().ToList();// Getting 300 records

 var config = new CsvConfiguration();
 config.RegisterClassMap<ExportInvoicesCsvMap>();

_csvWriter = new CsvWriter(new CsvFileWriter(_fullPath), config);
_csvWriter.WriteRecords(result);
_csvWriter.Dispose();
```

But I am still getting whole Invoice Model data in csv.

Comment: Are you sure the `Invoice` in `CsvClassMap<Invoice>` is the same type as the `Invoice` in `List<Invoice>`? Because I can only reproduce what you see if I provide a non-related type in the CsvClassMap.

Comment: Yes its same model.

Answer (score 0):

CsvHelper works correcting without ignoring properties. Might be you are missing some thing. Please check below code.

```
 public class Invoice
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ExportInvoicesCsvMap : CsvClassMap<Invoice>
{
    public ExportInvoicesCsvMap()
    {
        Map(i => i.Number).Index(0).Name("Number");
        Map(i => i.SupplierName).Index(1).Name("Supplier Name");

    }
}

        var config = new CsvConfiguration();
        config.RegisterClassMap<ExportInvoicesCsvMap>();
        List<Invoice> list = new List<Invoice>();
        list.Add(new Invoice
        {
            Number = 1,
            SupplierName = "SN",
            Amount=7
        });

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"test.csv"))
        {
            var _csvWriter = new CsvWriter(sw, config);
            IEnumerable records = list;
            _csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
        }
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Its exact same but having no luck. I have latest version installed (2.16.3)

Comment: Can you share your exact code, so that I could look into it.

Comment: That would require lot of editing in class but code is same rest of the code is unrelated.

Comment: Do not use CsvFileWriter instead use StreamWriter.

Comment: Still same result.

Comment: Can you share you solution file.